# why does cargo rebuild for each of `cargo flamegraph`, `cargo asm --profile release`, 'cargo run --profile release`?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

If I run these three commands in succession (no modifications to the source code), each one takes considerable time to compile, even though they should be all building the exact same release binary. They all say the same thing in the output, `release [optimized + debuginfo]`.

```
    Finished release [optimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 18.62s
```

why might this be happening, and/or how can I get more visibility to debug it (e.g. maybe `cargo flamegraph` or `cargo asm` sets some environment variable that causes a rebuild?)